# How do I set Zsh up in iTerm2 to match Terminal?

Tags: terminal, zsh, osx-elcapitan, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I'm new to development & stack overflow so hopefully my question will be phrased correctly.

Q: How is it that within OS X El Capitan Terminal my Ruby, Rails, & RVM versions are correct, but within iTerm Zsh, it does not reflect the same information. I set up Zsh & honukai theme for aesthetic & practical purposes > standard terminal. How do I set up iTerm2 to reflect the same data. As you can see Ruby is showing an older version besides my best attempt to have it as 2.3.1 (which is set to the default and current within RVM list in iTerm2) and Rails is showing not installed ('rvm not a function' problem within iTerm, but no issue with using rvm as a function within Terminal).

I do want the issue solved, but I also care more about knowing exactly why the problem is occurring in the first place so that I understand the difference between Terminal and iTerm2 Zsh better.

Thanks!

Link to Gyazo image since I do not have 10 reputation to post images.
Comparison Images:

https://gyazo.com/2f4051557e2da6745ff40d2a72e5c568

Zsh rvm list even though ruby -v showing as 2.0.0:

https://gyazo.com/ec2e483adb6287fd409537f4ede59fd2

Comment: To better rephrase my my question, or to phrase it in another way;

In order to make the version of ruby update, every time I open iTerm2 I have to type "rm use ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0 --create" in order to get ruby -v to indicate 2.3.1 And afterwards Rails ceases to exist until  [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"   is input. Everytime I close iTerm, I have to do this again once it's open to update. How can I make this permanent? So that when i close and reopen iTerm Zsh, I don't have to do this.

Comment: can't see the image, can you post it to https://imgur.com/ and paste the link? that is the default website where SO stores images.